# Make my google home verify an oral code

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I would like to build an app with a oral code verification.

i could just set my cde in dialogflow before then, juste verify it.

```
GH : "For continue, give me the code"
Me : " 1 2 3 4"
GH " Access granted" / "Access denied"
```

But how can do an input a get this code on dialogflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - consider if you really want to do this. Having someone say a passcode out loud isn't really very secure and adds very little additional security in a multi-user environment.

There are two stages to this - the first is setting up an Intent to handle this, specifically in the format you want, and the second would be handling and verifying this is the correct code.

**Setting up the Intent**

We'll need two intents - one that prompts and sets a context so we know we're expecting the validation code, and one that checks for the code.

The prompting intent might look something like this:

[image]

The notable part here is that it is setting an *output context*. We'll see why that matters in a moment.

The one to handle numeric input might look like this:

[image]

There is a lot more to this one. First note that we're requiring an input context that matches the output context from the last Intent. This means that this Intent should only match if that Context has been set. This lets us talk about numbers elsewhere in our conversation without triggering this validation.

Next we're looking for sequences of numbers that match the `@sys.number-sequence` built-in Entity type. There are other entity types that may be useful for you - see the [documentation for details](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#numbers) and pick one that makes sense or experiment to find what works best in your case.

Finally, we're going to use a webhook for fulfillment to verify if the code is correct. Which is the next session...

**Verifying the code**

While there are ways to do the verification without a webhook, this is really the most straightforward way to do it. If you're using Google's library to handle input from Dialogflow, you can get the value with something like

```
var code = app.getArgument('number-sequence');
```

using whatever the parameter name is. If you're not using the library, you can find this in the JSON at `result.parameters.number-sequence`.

You would then verify this code, however you want, and return a message indicating if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a sequence of numbers as your code you can use the `@sys.number-sequence` entity to recognize it and then check the code in your webhook.

Another way would be to simply make a custom entity 'code' that has an entry of '1234'.